# How to break this loop? (python)

Tags: python, loops, break

```
    available_fruits = ['apple', 'grape', 'banana']
    
    choice = input('Please pick a fruit I have available: ')
    
    while True : choice= input('You made an invalid choice. Please pick again:') 
            if choice not in available_fruits 
                 else print('You can have the fruit')
```

I want to make this loop stop when user inputs something in the list "available_fruits".
But when I enter 'apple', it says "You can have the fruit" but as well as "You made an invalid choice. Please pick again:" again.

How can I make this loop to stop when I enter the fruit which is in the list? when I put the "break" at the end of the code, it says its an invalid syntax..

Comment: That code is not (valid) Python, where indentation matters. Please extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question, so people don't have to guess what the code is that causes problems. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Use the while condition instead of just while True,
something like this works:

```
available_fruits = ['apple', 'grape', 'banana']

choice = input('Please pick a fruit I have available: ')

while choice not in available_fruits: 
    choice= input('You made an invalid choice. Please pick again:')

print('You can have the fruit')
```

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
available_fruits = ['apple', 'grape', 'banana']

choice = input('Please pick a fruit I have available: ')

while True:
    if choice in available_fruits:
        print('You can have the fruit')
        break
    else:
        choice = input('You made an invalid choice. Please pick again: ')
```

But in general I'd suggest you create while loops with an actual condition. That's what while-loops are for. They automatically break when the condition evaluates to False. It's much cleaner, too.

Example:

```
available_fruits = ['apple', 'grape', 'banana']

choice = input('Please pick a fruit I have available: ')

while choice not in available_fruits:
    choice = input('You made an invalid choice. Please pick again: ')

print('You can have the fruit')
```

Comment: This still complains about making an invalid choice on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: thank you, you're right :D I edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. Assuming you need to use break.

```
available_fruits = ['apple', 'grape', 'banana']

choice = input('choose a fruit: ')
while True : 
    if choice in available_fruits:
        print('you picked a valid fruit')
        break
    else:
        choice = input('choose a fruit: ')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if its the formatting of your question of if that's your actual code. You some have syntax errors:

- At the end of every `if` or `else` you need to use `:` as you did with the `while` condition.
- You must use the correct indentation.

Once you fix those errors, check the condition you want to meet in order to get out of the loop with `break`.